# Finding Distinct Value of a field in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a database within a cosmosdb container and I am trying to find all the distinct values within a nested field.

The structure looks like this:

```
{
"id": "1111111111111",
"feedback": {

    "Feedback_Source": "test"
 }
}
```

This is my code, however, I keep getting this error (unable tonset property headers of undefined or null reference ) when trying to execute this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value c.feedback.Feedback_Source from c
```

Any Suggestion or advice is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing something wrong somewhere? I've just created a new database, with a new container, with partition key "id", and copy/pasted the item structure 3 times with different "id" and "Feedback_Source" values, then executed your query and got the expected results. All was done from the portal.

Comment: Let me try again. It mentions ‘header error’

Comment: I keep getting this error : unable tonset property headers of undefined or null reference - I am looking into this now

Comment: The error must be somewhere else, it's not the query. (You can confirm this by running it in the portal). What are you using to execute it?

Comment: I am just within the portal using a sql query within my container in azure cosmosdb. You are right because I tried this in another container and it worked. It may be something with just that container.